# Run a function of an Oracle package from a query in Access 2010

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access-2010

I have a package named PACK1, inside have a function named FUNCION1.
Then in Access2010 y created a new Query like:

```
SELECT A.COLUMN1, PACK1.FUNCTION1(A.COLUMN1) FROM TABLE1 A
```

But Access2010 notice me "PACK1.FUNCTION1" IT IS NOT DEFINED IN EXPRESSION

Help me please!

Comment: please show us the definition code for `PACK1`

Comment: Use a passthrough query if you want to use Oracle functions in Access. Else it won't work.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan It's necesary?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Please, Can you give me an example?

Comment: [Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/process-sql-on-a-database-server-by-using-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42)